# Internacionalizar o conteúdo das Meta Tags HTML

Tags: html

Devemos internacionalizar o conteúdo das Meta Tags `HTML` como `description` e `keywords`?

1. Esta internacionalização prejudica a indexificação pelo google já que ele só irá analisar a página em um único idioma?
2. O usuário poderá encontrar o site se pesquisar uma palavra chave que coincide com a palavra chave do idioma não padrão?

Comment: Interessante pergunta, pensei em colocar uma recompensa mas deixo como sugestão pro AP ;)

Comment: Não faço a minima ideia, aguardando para ver.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade não é uma internacionalização, é padrão Google, a indexação ocorre lendo dessa maneira. e ajuda muito na indexação de buscas do Google, o sistema do `google` identifica automaticamente seu padrão de linguagem do site, não sendo necessário nenhuma tradução

claro que as metas tags vc colocara em linguagem padrão do site, em português
tipo

```
<meta name="title" content="agencia de Publicidade em Cuiaba" />
<meta name="description" content="publicidade  cuiaba">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Depende de seu público alvo. Se a página tiver uma grande probabilidade de ser acessada em diversas linguagens, melhor não especificar a linguagem da página.
2. Provavelmente sim, pois o motor de busca procurará a palavra em si independente de seu significado, caso não seja especificada uma linguagem padrão na página.

Caso o site estiver escrito em dois idiomas (ex: EN e PT), recomendo criar uma página para cada idioma, assim um visitante do exterior poderá ser direcionado imediatamente para a página de seu idioma através do site de busca

Answer (score 0):

O que deves fazer é colocar os meta-tags no mesmo idioma do site..
Até porque a google faz uma verificação da concistencia das keywords..
Ou seja verifica se existe mesmo o conteudo relacionado.

Caso tenhas multi idiomas no teu site. Preenchees o meta-tags com o idioma correspondente.

No entanto deixo aqui um guia de SEO feito pela GOOGLE, é grande ajuda.
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/pt-PT//intl/pt-BR/webmasters/docs/guia-otimizacao-para-mecanismos-de-pesquisa-pt-br.pdf

Caso tenhas mais alguma duvida é só perguntares :)

Outra coisa não te esqueças de colocares o teu site no GOOGLE WEB MASTERS